# WAR won't deploy on different machine

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a situation with a Java Servlet application. Initially a "dev" version was created, then when complete we created a "test" and then a "live".  All 3 (Dev, Test and Live) deploy and run fine on my development PC.  But when we transfer to the server, Dev and Test deploy and start fine but Live will simply NOT START.  I am using the same version of Java JRE and Tomcat on both machines (Windows XP development PC and Windows Server on server).

Can someone please tell me what might be wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Here is the Tomcat console output

```
07-Jan-2014 10:50:17 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting propert
y 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Orion' did not find a matching propert
y.
07-Jan-2014 10:50:17 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
07-Jan-2014 10:50:17 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
07-Jan-2014 10:50:17 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
07-Jan-2014 10:50:17 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
07-Jan-2014 10:50:17 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 911 ms
07-Jan-2014 10:50:17 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
07-Jan-2014 10:50:17 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
07-Jan-2014 10:50:22 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init>
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
07-Jan-2014 10:50:22 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener    
contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
07-Jan-2014 10:50:22 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener 
contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
07-Jan-2014 10:50:22 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\PPSLDev.war
07-Jan-2014 10:50:27 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init>
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
07-Jan-2014 10:50:27 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener 
contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
07-Jan-2014 10:50:27 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener 
contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
07-Jan-2014 10:50:27 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\PPSLTest.war
07-Jan-2014 10:50:31 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init>
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
07-Jan-2014 10:50:31 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener 
contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
07-Jan-2014 10:50:31 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener 
contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
07-Jan-2014 10:50:31 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\docs
07-Jan-2014 10:50:32 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\examples
07-Jan-2014 10:50:32 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\host-manager
07-Jan-2014 10:50:32 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\manager
07-Jan-2014 10:50:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT
07-Jan-2014 10:50:33 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
07-Jan-2014 10:50:33 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
07-Jan-2014 10:50:33 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
07-Jan-2014 10:50:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 16115 ms
```

Regards

AJF

Comment: Post console output, etc. Also, is this application attempting to write to a location inside itself?

Comment: chrylis, I have added the console output.  The war files are PPSLDev.war, PPSLTest.war and PPSL.war

Comment: I can't see any error

Comment: Logs look fine. It seems that tomcat isn't picking up the `PPSL.war` at all. Even if the war file was curropt or anything, tomcat still would have complained about a `ZipExcpetion`. ( I know it may sound stupid) but make sure that the war is indeed present in the `webapps` and that (if you are using context based deployments) the relevant context is mapped in the context.xml for this war

Comment: Thanks Saif but forgive me for not completely understanding, I am still learning Java and Tomcat.  What exactly is "context based deployment"?  Is this where the java servlet has its own context.xml file and the app is deployed through this context.xml file?  I am not sure how to do that.  I am using the general context.xml file in the conf directory in Tomcat!

Comment: The question has been answered now so can be taken off hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server.xml, you can control which apps you can deploy and how. There are many options that you can control from contexts ([link here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html)) .

Let me give you can example entry of server.xml in tomcat

```
<Context docBase="AppName" path="/AnyAppContext" reloadable="false" crossContext="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:AppName">
</Context>
```

Now when tomcat loads up , it will search for the war name `AppName.war` in the deployments folder (webapps/wtpwebapps) and deploy it on context path `/AnyAppContext`. So now your application `AppName.war` will be available at path `http://someHost:port/AnyAppContext`.

Now for the issue that you are facing, make sure that the relevant entries exist for all 3 of your applications. Check the paths and the name of the apps

Comment: Thanks Saif again.  This has helped and I have the WAR running but not sure if what I have done is correct.  Let me know what you think before I tick your answer.  I looked at the server.xml on the server machine and it had one Context XML element like yours above excpet that the reloadable attribute was et to "true" and it had no attribute of crossContext.  I commented out the entire Context xml element and the WAR started.  Is this acceptable practise?  Is there a preferred way to do this?

Comment: There isn't any issue in running your application by declaring contexts or just by the default tomcat behaviour. Although there are multiple reasons for using either, I can list down one fundamental purpose of running via contexts is that you can enforce your tomcat instance to run ONLY the applications that you have declared in the context and that no other war (placed intentionally or not) in the webapps will get loaded. You can say that this is sort of a security feature to make sure that your tomcat instance is not running anything else than the apps you want it to run.

Comment: Thanks Saif.  This is all good advice.  I am slowly getting to a decent level of knowledge with Java and Tomcat (previously Unix and Oracle background you see).  I will tinker around with the Context to try and get them all working that way.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)